# How can a shell encryption program use less user time?

Tags: c, profiling

**Update2:**

Ported to autotools and uploaded to [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/shellcrypt/).

**Update:**

I am going to run a few more rigorous tests on this but I believe the issue is related to caching and ordering of the two test cases may be significant.  Also I know the encryption is pathetic, duplicated in two files, and the code is less than first draft quality.  I also know that I should be using makefiles etc.  I am not proposing using this anywhere.  I whipped it together and simplified it down to get the best input from others that I could.

**Original Question:**

I am totally stumped.  I created a wrapper to encrypt shell scripts based on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728706/recommendations-for-encrypting-decrypting-scripts-elegantly) and it works well; however, in determining the performance issues with it the encrypted scripts take less user time!  Can you help explain that to me?  I just don't get it.  I have stripped everything down to the basics and simplified it as much as possible.  If you pick up my files you will have to have write permissions to the file /usr/bin/shelldecrypt.

```
    ojblass@XXXXX:~/source/shellcrypt>./build
    ojblass@XXXXX:~/source/shellcrypt>./run 

    example.sh.bin is encrypted run it to view output
    ojblass@XXXXX:~/source/shellcrypt>./profile
    example.sh
    real    0m0.107s 
    user    0m0.048s 
    sys     0m0.052s 

    example.sh.bin
    real    0m0.118s 
    user    0m0.036s
    sys     0m0.068s
    ojblass@XXXXX:~/source/shellcrypt>
```

**[build]**

```
    gcc shellencrypt.c
    mv a.out shellencrypt
    gcc shelldecrypt.c
    mv a.out shelldecrypt
    cp shelldecrypt /usr/bin
```

**[example.sh]**

```
    #!/bin/bash
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
    ls -lt  >> /dev/null
```

**[profile]**

```
    echo example.sh
    time example.sh
    echo example.sh.bin
    time example.sh.bin
```

**[run]**

```
    rm -rf example.sh.bin
    ./shellencrypt example.sh
    chmod 755 example.sh.bin
    echo example.sh.bin is encrypted run it to view output
```

[shelldecrypt.c]

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <string.h>
#include        <limits.h>
#include        <unistd.h>
/* #define DEBUG */
static int    flip( int a)
{
        int b;
        b = a;
        b ^= 0x000C;
        return b;
}

static void    trace ( char * szMessage )
{
#ifdef DEBUG
     if (szMessage != NULL)
     {
       printf("DEBUG Message %s\n",szMessage);
     }
#endif
    return;
}

int     main(int argc, char     *argv[]) {

        FILE    *fp = NULL;
        int     ch=(char) 0;
        int     foundnl=0;
        char    shellpath[4096]; /* what happened to PATH_MAX? */
        char    *ptest;
        FILE    *pipe = NULL;

        /* TODO REMOVE memset(bangline, 0, sizeof(bangline)); */

        trace("STARTING");
        trace(argv[0]);
        trace("ARGUMENT");

        /* get the shell environment variable */
        ptest = getenv("SHELL");
        if (ptest == NULL)
        {
            trace("could not get shell environment variable");
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(shellpath, getenv("SHELL"));
            trace(shellpath);
        }

        if ((argc >=1) && (argv[1]!=NULL))
        {
            trace(argv[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("(null)");
        }

        if (argc == 2) {
                fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
                if (fp == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file %s. Exiting.\n",argv[1]);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        else
        {
               printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
               exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        /* strip out the bangline which is not encryped */
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
              if (ch == 10)
              {
                 foundnl = 1;
                 break;
              }
        }


        if (foundnl!=1)
        {
           (void) fclose(fp);
           trace("FOUND NO NEWLINE BEFORE END OF FIRST LINE");
           return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }


        pipe = popen(shellpath, "w");
        if (pipe == NULL)
        {
            trace("popen failed");
            (void) fclose(fp);
            return (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
            trace("writing string to pipe");

            while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
               (void) fputc(flip(ch),pipe);
            }
/*            (void) fputc(EOF,pipe); */
        }

        if (pipe != NULL)
           (void) pclose(pipe);
        if (fp != NULL)
           (void) fclose(fp);
        exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

[shellencrypt.c]

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <string.h>

static int    flip( int a)
{
        int b;
        b = a;
        b ^= 0x000C;
        return b;
}

int     main(int argc, char     *argv[]) {

        FILE    *fp = NULL, *fpOut=NULL;
        int             ch;

        char szOutputFileName[2000];
        strcpy(szOutputFileName,"");


        if (argc == 2) {
                fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
                if (fp == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file %s. Exiting.\n",argv[1]);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
        }
        else
        {
               printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n",argv[0]);
               exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        strcpy(szOutputFileName, argv[1]);
        strcat(szOutputFileName, ".bin");

        fpOut = fopen(szOutputFileName,"wt");
        if (fpOut == NULL)
        {
             fprintf(stderr,"Unable to open file %s.  Exiting.\n",szOutputFileName);
             if (fp)
                 (void) fclose(fp);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        /* print the header */
        fprintf(fpOut,"#!/usr/bin/shelldecrypt\n");

        /* read until the end of file, encrypting characters and writing them out to target file */
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
              (void) fputc(flip(ch),fpOut);
        }
        if (fp)
           (void) fclose(fp);
        if (fpOut)
           (void) fclose(fpOut);

        return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: DO you get the same figures if you reverse the order of running the shell & binary versions? And if you run the test 10 times with randomised order and average the times, what figures do you get?

Comment: hmmmm they are the same now...

Comment: I guess when your neck deep in something you don't consider the simple stuff...

Comment: I'd like to point out that your decryption depends on the value of the users SHELL environment variable; if they set that to something that writes the contents out to a file they can read, then they can get the contents of the script that you are trying to hide. Also, what if the user just has csh set as their shell instead of bash? Then this whole thing will break. You should probably at least feed the output to /bin/sh so you know what interpreter will be running the script.

Comment: The one thing I rely on is ksh being installed.  I agree that taking out the use of shell is necessary.  The commercial product I was looking out writes to a temporary file.  I wanted to avoid that as well as the HUGE price tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a significant enough difference that I would conclude there's any effect.  A better "profile" is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo example.sh
/usr/bin/time sh -c 'for i in $(seq 1 1000); do ./example.sh; done'

echo example.sh.bin
/usr/bin/time sh -c 'for i in $(seq 1 1000); do ./example.sh.bin; done'
```

On my machine, I got:

```
example.sh
39.46user 33.22system 1:16.92elapsed 94%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+8547221minor)pagefaults 0swaps
example.sh.bin
42.33user 42.13system 1:33.98elapsed 89%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 0maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+9376313minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

That is not enough to show *definitively* that the "encrypted" one is slower (though I obviously think it is), but it certainly shows that the encrypted *doesn't* consistently take less user time in a simple benchmark.

Also, there are some other serious issues with your code.  Most obviously, this isn't close to sound encryption.  As other people said, you're approaching the problem wrong.  A encryption algorithm you come up with "in a matter of hours" is not a substitute for sound permissions.

Further, you need to use makefiles instead of proliferating unnecessary shell scripts.  Learn rudimentary gcc options, like -o.  Don't attempt to copy to /usr/bin/ unless the user runs an install target (in which case /usr/local/bin would still be better).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I do know better but I get lazy during proof of concepts.  The code less than first draft quality.

Comment: I am looking at real encryption algorithms but this was too simple to pass up for a proof of concept.

Comment: I had forgotten about $seq I was using let and a silly while variable a minute ago +1

Comment: I find it a bit strange that time outputs the pagefault information and other stuff given this new profile scheme...

Comment: /usr/bin/time is different from the shell built-in time.  However, they both provide user time.

Comment: Mathew I wrapped it up in autotools and uploaded a copy to sourceforge.  Thanks again.  You can find the code at https://sourceforge.net/projects/shellcrypt/

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is basically showing that the encryption isn't a significant part of the performance of this particular script.

However, getting the file system to load the contents of the directory *the first time* is significant. Once it's loaded, it's likely to be cached. That would explain why the first time you run both, whichever one is executed first will be slower. After that they're likely to be very similar, using the file system cache.

If you reboot (to make absolutely sure you're clearing the cache) and run it the other way round, I'd expect the encrypted version to take longer, simply because it'll be going to disk instead of the cache.

Comment: Reversing them equalized stuff but I tend to agree that caching and other complexities are hiding underneath.  Lesson learned thank you for your time Jon.

Comment: This is a good point. A way to remove fs effects would be to just use echos in the example.sh script.